# Is it possible to disable batch on windows?

Tags: batch-file

I maintain a CICD infrastructure which runs Windows jobs. Pipelines can run arbitrary code, including custom .bat/.cmd scripts.

I found that batch does not propagate exit code properly in many cases, so developers often see that their jobs succeed, even if bash equivalent of such script would have failed (properly). So I want to forbid execution of batch in CICD pipelines. If a job executes batch script anyhow, I would like to fail with an error message saying that it's forbidden.

The problem is that you never know when and which process will execute batch script - it can be `make` or custom python script. Is there a way to ban execution of .bat/.cmd scripts in a given `powershell` terminal session or `cmd` terminal session?

Maybe there's a way to uninstall batch interpreter, or maybe patch it?

Comment: Does [How to Disable the Windows Command Prompt or PowerShell](https://www.makeuseof.com/windows-disable-command-prompt-powershell/) answer your question?

Comment: It is not possible to completely disable batch processing on Windows, as batch files are a fundamental part of the operating system's command line functionality. However, you can choose not to use batch files or limit their usage by using alternative scripting languages, such as PowerShell or Python. Additionally, you can restrict the execution of batch files by using security measures, such as modifying the system's user account control settings or using antivirus software.